# How to recalculate table created by CTAS?

Tags: impala

I have created table using this statement:
`CREATE TABLE tablename STORED AS PARQUET AS (SELECT ...)`

How can i recalculate it without DROP TABLE - CREATE TABLE flow?

Answer (score 0):

In Impala, The INSERT INTO syntax appends data to a table. The existing data files are left as-is, and the inserted data is put into one or more new data files.

The INSERT OVERWRITE syntax replaces the data in a table. Currently, the overwritten data files are deleted immediately; they do not go through the HDFS trash mechanism.

So If you want to replace the data in the table `tablename` without undergoing drop table and create table, you can run a query like this

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tablename SELECT * from <source_tablename>;
```